# getting details of topics in a program(node)

Tags: ros, c++, subscribe, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys

I want to get details about topics in a program(node) such as how many topic exists in ros or the list of topic's name or how many node that subscribes from a special topic..

I want to get these details in cpp file not in terminal ..

is there any way to get this details?

any suggestion about this?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140526/getting-details-of-topics-in-a-program(node)/) by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1769 on 2014-03-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosnode info [node name]` has a lot of that info: http://wiki.ros.org/rosnode.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2014-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-03-16**:
I want to get these details in cpp not in terminal ...